# Get http://host-ip:9100/metrics: context deadline exceeded,

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

On prometheus server /target i get this error : - Get http://host-ip:9100/metrics: context deadline  exceeded. I can curl the metrics from prometheus server using curl http://node_exporter-ip:9100/metrics. It takes around 10s. I changed scrape_timeout to 20s. still no change in status of node_host. Could anyone suggest any fix to issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the host-ip displayed by the prometheus server is the right server to query.

Comment: I also have some problems, just suddenly appears, I delete the pods, and it's back to normal, and now deleting the pods is not the solution anymore. so weird, I don't do anything, but out of nowhere, it's down.